# JavaScript program that will ask for any amount, and output the number of icecandies that can be bought, and the change if any

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I need help with this I don't even think it is right as I have a hard time understanding loops. I was asked to create a Javascript Program that asks for any amount and outputs the number of ice candies that can be bought, and the change if any. My problem is that I do not know if "while" is the correct thing to put or "do" or if I'm missing something Thank you in advance. Here is my code

```js
function minitask() {
  var m = document.getElementById("money").value;
  var c = 8.5;

  m = m - c;
  c = c + 1;

  while (m <= c)
    alert("You can buy " + c + " Icecandy and your change is " + m);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="money" name= "Enter any amount">
<button onclick="minitask()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Please may you fix the syntax errors? Also, use [`.valueAsNumber`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#valueasnumber) instead of `.value`. That way it will be a number not a string.

Comment: That doesn’t look like valid code. The first step to troubleshooting is observing the output. So what happens? What’s in the F12 console?

Comment: you're missing an end bracket `}` in your function

Comment: looks like the solution to this problem is a simple division. I don't think you really need a loop to solve it.

Comment: Yes this ^. You don't need a loop, `Math.floor(value / cost)`

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues in your code both from a algorithmic point of view and a software design point of view.

#### Algorithmic

There is no need to use a loop here, you can do a simple division which will give you the number of candies you can buy:

```
available money / price for one candy = number of candies to buy
```

You need to [`floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) the result as you cannot buy e.g. `1.2` candys.

The change can then be calculated by

```
change = available money - number of candies to buy * price of one candy
```

#### Software design

- You should treat variables as [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) when there is no need to mutate the variables so use `const` instead of `var` to declare variables.
- variable names should describe the values they are holding to make code more readable. Your variable names don't tell anything making the code unnecessarily hard to read and if it was a more complex problem this could make your code unreadable.
- You should use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of concatenating strings, which will also make your code more readable.
- if you expect a number to be put in you can use `type=number` for the `<input>`. There are also more option like setting `min` and `max` which would make sense in your case as e.g. there is no *negative money*. See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number).
- if you want to display something within the `<input>` use the `placeholder` attribute, not `name`.
- You can use [`valueAsNumber`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#valueasnumber) on an `<input>` element which will retrieve a number right away instead of a `string`. Together with input type `number` this will make sure you always get a number returned.

#### Working solution

```js
function minitask() {
  const moneyAvailable = document.getElementById("money").valueAsNumber;
  if(moneyAvailable < 0) {
    alert(`You cannot buy anything with negative money!`)
    return;
  }
  const priceForIceCandy = 8.5;

  const noIceCandies = Math.floor(moneyAvailable / priceForIceCandy);
  const change = moneyAvailable - noIceCandies * priceForIceCandy; 
  alert(`You can buy ${noIceCandies} Icecandy and your change is ${change}`);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="money" min="0" placeholder="Enter any amount">
<button onclick="minitask()">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

- First you would need to check if the money is enough to buy something
- `If` it is you should divide the amount of money by the cost of an icecandy, it's true that the classic divider `/` doesn't give the change but there is an operator that does, which is called [modulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)

  then return all of that informations to the user
- `Else` if the user doesn't have enough money tell him that he needs more !